# How to pattern match a function in Scala?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to pattern match functions in scala ? Specially the return type of the function.

Here is an example. I'm trying to print Shoe if the function's return type is Shoe or Bag otherwise.

```
object Test extends App {

  trait ProductItem {
    val name: String
    val price: Int
  }

  case class Product(partialPerson: (String) => ProductItem)
  case class Shoe(name: String)(val price: Int) extends ProductItem
  case class Bag(name: String)(val price: Int) extends ProductItem

  val shoe = Shoe("nike")(_)
  val bag = Bag("addidas")(_)

  def printType(shoe: (Int) => ProductItem): Unit = {
    shoe match {
      case isShoe: ((Int) => Shoe) =>
        println("Is a shoe")
      case isBag: ((Int) => Bag) =>
        println("Is a bag")
    }
  }

  printType(shoe)
  printType(bag)
}
```

**Output:**
Is a shoe 
Is a shoe

**Expected output:**
Is a shoe 
Is a bag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the type erasure in compile time:

```
<console>:17: warning: non-variable type argument Bag in type pattern Int => Bag is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

You can solve it by using [TypeTags](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html):

```
def printType[T](shoe: (Int) => T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Unit = {
    shoe match {
      case isShoe if tag.tpe =:= typeOf[Shoe]=>
        println("Is a shoe")
      case isBag if tag.tpe =:= typeOf[Bag] =>
        println("Is a bag")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there much perf cost to this? Or is it fine to do in a cross-cutting concern method (logging/metrics)

Answer (score 2):

When compiling this code you get a compiler warning tha explains the problem -

> Warning:(20, 25) non-variable type argument c.n.p.Shoe in type
>   pattern Int => c.n.p.Shoe is unchecked since it is eliminated by
>   erasure
>         case isShoe: (Int => Shoe) =>
>                           ^

a possible solution around it -

```
  def printType[T <: ProductItem : ClassTag](item: Int => T): Unit = {
    implicitly[ClassTag[T]] match {
      case ClassTag(s) if s == classOf[Shoe] =>
        println("Is a shoe")
      case ClassTag(b) if b == classOf[Bag] =>
        println("Is a bag")
    }
  }
```

To understand this solution you'll have to be familiar with implicit parameters & ClassTag type.